# jQuery scrollTop() not scrolling to desired location

Tags: jquery

I have a comment system I've created that I want to have reply buttons once clicked to take you to the reply box. Here is my code:

```
$('.reply-button').click(function(){ 
   $('#reply-' + $(this).closest(".root-comment").attr("id")).animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top});
   $('#reply-' + $(this).closest(".root-comment").attr("id") + ' textarea').focus();
});

// How I get the root comment's ID
$(this).closest(".root-comment").attr("id");
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Sorry to waste everyone's time. It was a div that was closed too soon issue. I apologize.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: It was actually due to a closing div tag. I'm sorry, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please delete or self answer your question.